# Change Breadcrumb URL for one module in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a module in yii2 project for which i want to change the breadcrumb `home` url link to a specific controller. I looked online but some docs say that change the project home url and it will be done but i dont want to change the project home url. I want to change it for only one page.

I got this code for `yii` but could not find anything similar for `yii2`

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
'links' => $this->breadcrumbs,
'homeLink' => CHtml::link('HOME - My Way', Yii::app()->homeUrl),
)); ?>
```

Also wants to know how to change the home url for whole project so that when i  write the code `$this->goHome()` it takes to the home page of the project.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly [breadcrumbs widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-breadcrumbs.html)

About Your question. 
To set your homePage for whole project You can simply add `'homeUrl' => '/path',` in your config file.

To set homePage for just one page You can do it by `Yii::$app->setHomeUrl('/path');` in place where You'd like to change it.